# Windows containers volume file permission issue

Tags: apache, docker, containers, docker-for-windows, windows-container

I am trying to set up a PHP+Apache development environment using Docker containers on Windows 10.

```
PS H:\> docker version
Client:
 Version:       17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:05:22 2017
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:        Wed Dec 27 20:15:52 2017
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

My container is a window's container with `microsoft/windowsservercore` as the base image.

One issue I face is when the source code is mounted via volume, the apache doesn't like the file permissions. `No input file specified.` is the displayed error. `access.log` gives `"GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 404 25`

This is the file permission inside the container with the mounted volume.

```
PS C:\www> get-acl .\info.php | format-list
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\www\info.php
Owner  : O:S-1-5-21-1258723895-351397710-2907126007-1740
Group  : G:S-1-5-21-1258723895-351397710-2907126007-513
Access : BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
     BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
     NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  Modify, Synchronize
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-1258723895-351397710-2907126007-1740G:S-1-5-21 . 
  -1258723895-351397710-2907126007-513D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BA
     )(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)
```

When I copy `info.php` into the container, apache works normally.

```
PS C:\www>
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\www\info.php
Owner  : User Manager\ContainerAdministrator
Group  : User Manager\ContainerAdministrator
Access : BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
     User Manager\ContainerAdministrator Allow  FullControl
     BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-93-2-1G:S-1-5-93-2-1D:(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)
  (A;ID;FA;;;S
     -1-5-93-2-1)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)
```

My workaround is the to use `Robocopy` to copy from the mounted volume folder to the `DocumentRoot`. The problem is I have to wait for a few seconds for source code changes to be reflected in the container.

Is there a better solution?